# allow users to create forms within android survey/data collection app

Tags: android, xml, database, json, survey

I'm trying to develop an Android app that could be used by advocacy groups or campaigners such that they would be able to create their own forms (surveys) for which they can go out canvassing and collect opinion data from people who don't have Internet connections and thus can't take surveys/polls online. Could also be used at events or anything else that requires data collection "in the field"

The benefit is allowing data collection on the spot without having to transfer data from paper to the office computer by hand.

I've been looking over this tutorial by Frank Abelson: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-andddyntut/section6.html

And have also been pouring through the Open Data Kit, but the ODK is a little more intense than I am prepared for and the Abelson tutorial doesn't discuss much how users could create their own forms.

I suppose users could just create their own XML files for custom forms in the office and store them on the server, but I was wondering if there was a way for them to do this on the Android app?

Just a hint about possible architecture or simple resources would be helpful, I am having a hard time picturing the solution at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i'm one of the developers of [open data kit](http://opendatakit.org). odk has been successfully deployed by organizations [all around the world](http://opendatakit.org/about/deployments/) for exactly what you describe.

we have a [graphical form designer](http://opendatakit.org/use/build) (and good alternatives in [purcforms](http://code.google.com/p/purcforms) and [xls2xforms](http://xform.childcount.org)), a [server to host the forms](http://opendatakit.org/use/aggregate), and an android [mobile client](http://opendatakit.org/use/client) (and good alternatives in [javarosa](http://bitbucket.org/javarosa/)). all the pieces are free, open source, and are driven by an active community.

if you could list what specifically about odk doesn't fit your needs (say, a need form design on the phone), i'd be could recommend alternatives...

Comment: Hi Yaw, definitely appreciate you replying to this question; you guys are doing excellent work with the ODK. 

I should have noted that I am also a bit of a beginner to Android and have chosen to do an app like this as a learning exercise.
I was trying to capture the bare bones of the app to understand how to put together a *very* simplified version of ODK collect that also allowed users to create a few of their own data fields on the phone, in the app itself. Not sure if JSON would be a more flexible approach than XML.
Are there any apps out there that would model this kind of function.

Comment: we use xforms because we didn't want to invent a new form description standard. rapid android and odk spreadsheet allow you to define questions and receive answers over sms to the phone, but i haven't seen anything like you want. i think what you describe is pretty cool and useful. whatever you build, i'd encourage you to make it xforms complaint so it can interoperate with other systems in our community.

Comment: Indeed, I will look more into xforms once I can get my fundamentals straightened out. Thank you again for the helpful advice.

Answer (score 2):

ODK is a fantastic open source solution. A potential commercial alternative you can also try is Canvas at http://www.gocanvas.com which allows you to replace paper based forms with your mobile device.

It currently runs on Android, Windows Mobile and BlackBerry with iPhone and iPad support coming soon. 
To get a quick overview of how to use Canvas:
  [Build a standard data collection app in 5 minutes and see it running on BlackBerry](http://www.gocanvas.com/content/blog/post/build-a-blackberry-data-collection-app-in-5-minutes) 
  [Build a signature capture app in 5 minutes and see it running on Android](http://www.gocanvas.com/content/blog/post/create-your-own-android-mobile-app-with-signature-capture-in-5-minutes)

Hope that helps some,
-Chris

Answer (score 2):

You should look into **[Fulcrum](http://www.fulcrumapp.com)**. I believe there is a 30 day trial period see if this software works for you. This is a one stop shop for mobile data collection teams. You can easily build your data collection forms right from your web account to include photo fields, text entry fields, choice fields, form sections, and repeatable sections. Repeatable, meaning parent-child relationships within a single data point.

They even have an App Gallery with a exemplary apps (forms) that allow you to use as a sort of "cheat-sheet" to get started. Here is the [political canvassing survey](http://fulcrumapp.com/apps/political-canvassing/) they posted.

-P.Reyes

Answer (score 2):

Check my project here: https://github.com/AndreiD/surveylib

PROS:  Simple solution, open source, without any overkill, you don't have to display any logos, it doesn't cost a thing, it's easy to be extended, material design etc.

CONS: You must have the server part, for the transmission of the answers data.

Comment: great! survey library .

Comment: This library seems not to be maintained anymore. Here would be a good alternative: https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/SurveyKit (does the same but with some additional features)

Comment: @Malte it's also a nice idea to state that you're the author of that library... :) don't be afraid, a little spam on other people's posts but with a small disclaimer didn't hurt anyone